# how to get the value from an event target in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

inside js function I'm receiving event as parameter, how do you get the value of the event target?

```
function myFn(event){
    ...
    close: function(event){
        var myVal = ... 
        /// should grab from 
        /// event-> arguments -> [0]->target -> property value painted in yellow (abc)        
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How is `myFn` invoked?

Comment: I though it was obvius that I need to get abc value from highlighted part of the image, mentioned on the comment also.

Answer (score 39):

Try:

```
var myVal = event.target.value;
```

Comment: Despite the lack of clarity in the question. I think this is the answer the OP is looking for.

Comment: Thanks this partially solves the problem, if I type fast enough myVal gets populated with first 4,5 letter, after that it stays on that no matter what I type afterwards. But if I wait couple of seconds then it updates the values again.

Comment: @user1765862 What event listener are you using?

Comment: Spent two hours in jQuery only to find that the solution is that simple.

Comment: probably using `onChange` event, you need `onInput`

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
(<HTMLInputElement>event.target).value
```

or

`event.target as HtmlInputlement`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```js
function($event) {
  const value = $event.target.value;
  ...
}
```

Comment: you can use event.target.getAttribute('value')